# Scraping articles and make google home read them

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a project with google home and google assistant, where my main focus is to scrape some data from a particular website and, via a webhook, make google Home read them.

I've been able to scrape the data i need using cheerio.js and request.js, and launching this script (which code i'll post below) from my terminal with 'node scraping_test.js' everything works fine.

As soon as i try to implement this into my index.js (js file i need to upload to my project) and upload it, the data i was able to scrape from terminal suddenly equal to null. Of course i added the required dependencies in the associated package.json, i have billing enabled, Apis enabled for this account and project and the webhook with simple text succeeds.
I deploy the function  by typing into terminal the following line:
    firebase deploy --only functions

Does anyone has any ida of how to make this work?

here is the code of my 'scraping_test.js'.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request("http://books.toscrape.com", function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Error: "+error);
  }
  console.log("Status code: "+response.statusCode);
  let data = [];
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('ul.nav.nav-list > li > ul ').each(function( index ) {
    var cat = $(this).find('ul > li > a').text().trim();
    console.log(cat);
   });
});
```

Comment: Is the API request working as expected? Do you see the status code?

Comment: Actually nope, I can't see it. I mean it's something like the changes i do to variables (like assigning a value or pushing variables into an array) equal to null when i exit the piece of code above. And if i try, for example, to run a agent.add to add those variables to the conversation with google assistant, it's like that line was skipped, because i can't see any conversation or so.

Comment: You may not have included the entire code snippet, but I think this may be an issue with asynchronous execution.

Comment: I think you're right. when i try just to execute this code snippet
`app.intent('get_http', (conv) => {
  request.get(url2, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      conv.close("Fail.");
    } else {
        console.log('success');
        conv.close("Success!");
      }
  })
})`
i get the http GET request on the url2, but nothing is displayed
The message i get in dialogflow is : "error": "No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"
Should i use a Promise then to make this work?

Comment: Yes you should be able to return a promise like `return request.get(...)` and it will wait until the promises have resolved.

Comment: Could you make an example of it? Because i tried implementing Promises but could make it work in dialogflow (while it works perfectly from terminal)

Comment: It should be something like: `app.intent(conv => { return new Promise(resolve, reject) { // Do async logic; conv.ask('123'); resolve() }})`